nodejs axios request playwright download zip
I made the following setup to be able to use user certificates in Playwright.
import { BrowserContext } from "playwright";
import request from "request";

/**
 * Configura o contexto do navegador para rotear todas as solicitações por meio
 * de um agente com certificado PKCS12.
 * @param context O contexto do navegador onde as rotas serão configuradas.
 * @param pfxBuffer O buffer do arquivo de certificado PKCS12 (.pfx).
 * @param passphrase A senha para desbloquear o arquivo de certificado PKCS12.
 */

export default async function setupBrowserContext(
  context: BrowserContext,
  pfxBuffer: Buffer,
  passphrase: string
) {
  await context.route("**/*", (route, req) => {
    const options = {
      uri: req.url(),
      method: req.method(),
      headers: req.headers(),
      body: req.postDataBuffer(),
      timeout: 10000,
      followRedirect: false,
      agentOptions: {
        pfx: pfxBuffer,
        passphrase: passphrase,
      },
    };
    let firstTry = true;
    const handler = function handler(err: any, resp: any, data: any) {
      if (err) {
        if (firstTry) {
          firstTry = false;
          return request(options, handler);
        }
        console.error(`Unable to call ${options.uri}`, err.code, err);
        return route.abort();
      } else {
        return route.fulfill({
          status: resp.statusCode,
          headers: resp.headers,
          body: data,
        });
      }
    };
    return request(options, handler);
  });
}

Navigation is occurring normally, but the download of .zip files is coming corrupted. I checked, and its size is much larger than expected when downloaded manually.
My suspicion is that this snippet of code lacks some configuration to redirect all necessary headers. I believe this because the request headers are default, and the size of this file being so much larger seems to be some form of encoding.
Below is the request header from a normal user:
POST ***?acao=download HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 62
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: ***
Host: ***
Origin: ***
Referer: ***
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="123", "Not:A-Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="123"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Linux"

And here's the request header from the Playwright bot:
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: **
Referer: **
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

the diff size of files is:



type access
Content-Length:




user
3979


bot
21064



The problem isn't with Playwright's download. I can download normally when I don't set up this configuration. The issue lies in using this configuration and downloading.

request is an old, deprecated library from a bygone era before promises. Playwright has built-in request that'd be better to use. Can you provide a URL and full code that I can run to reproduce the issue of the zip being corrupted?
